# Do bounded convex subsets form a group?

Tags: group-theory, convex-analysis

Convex sets are closed under the minkowski sum of convex sets. A reason this doesn't form a group is, some infinite convex sets absorb subsets in it. For eg, consider the half plane, and a vector inside the half plane. The sum of both is still the halfplane.

So, I thought, what if I consider bounded convex subsets, then do they form a group? Else, what more criteria do I need?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Are you assigning an algebraic structure to the nonempty sets so that $\{0\}$ is special?  For sufficiently rich abelian group $V$, there are definitely more maximal subsets which form groups under the minkowski sum.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh, I see your point now. You could take, for instance, $\{\Bbb Z+A\,:\, \emptyset\subseteq A\subseteq\Bbb R\}$. Still there are no inverses in the semigroup form the OP. I guess the true statement is that a subgroup $(\mathcal P(\Bbb R^n), +)$ never contains a set of finite, non-zero Lebesgue measure.